# Alinear navbar a la derecha con CSS3

Tags: css3, navbar

Necesito diseñar una página estática como está en esta imagen solo usando HTML y CSS3, tengo todo hecho lo único que no logro es que la palabra "LOGO" se vaya a la izquierda y los 3 elementos del navbar a la derecha, sin usar librerías.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno siguiendo con la explicación, la parte del header lo tengo de esta forma

```html
<header>
        <h1>logo</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Con respecto al CSS lo tengo configurado así, por lo que no sé como tendría que hacerlo para que quede como en la imagen

```css
header{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #E7EBDA;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 2em 20em;
}

header h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header ul{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0.5em auto;
    text-align: center;
}

header ul li{
    display: inline;
}

header ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #7D8471;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #7D8471;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.3em;
}

header ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #B8B799;
    border-color: #B8B799;
}

header ul li a:active{
    padding: 0.2em;
}
```

Comment: Hola, por casualidad estás usando bootstrap?

Comment: Bienvenido, añade el código por favor, la imagen en este caso se queda corta para poder ayudarte

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda es un ejercicio y no puedo usar librerías, solo tirar de html y css

Comment: Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: @Aprendiz lo intenté pero no me deja publicarlo porque dice que hay más código que texto

Comment: coloca explicación y código y solo aquel código que sea relevante a la pregunta; para lo que deseas resolver no es mucho lo que vas a publicar

Comment: @Ragnaval a ok, de todas formas podrías poner el código que llevas hecho? de esta forma podemos ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Ya puse el código que tengo hasta ahora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podría realizar lo de la siguiente manera con porcentajes y `display:inline-block`, alinea el título a la izquierda y el `<nav>` a la derecha:

```css
header{
    display: block;
    background-color: #E7EBDA;
    width:100%;
}

header h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;
    width:30%;
    display:inline-block;
}
header nav{
    text-align: right;
    display:inline-block;
    width:60%;
}

header ul{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0.5em auto;
    text-align: center;
}

header ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

header ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #7D8471;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #7D8471;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.3em;
}

header ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #B8B799;
    border-color: #B8B799;
}

header ul li a:active{
    padding: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <h1>logo</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Sí me sirvió, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Bueno en base a tus clases lo más rápido es usar la propiedad **float**, esta la aplico de la siguiente manera en tu css:

Primero al **header** le di un alto (height) de 50px

el float se aplica al **header h1** para que lo lleve a la izquierda y al **header ul** para que lo lleve a la derecha, creo que esta es la forma más rápida de hacerlo,porque después hay propiedades flex pero no sé si quieras saber eso ahora que estás partiendo. Ejecuta y ve lo en pantalla completa.

Saludos

```css
header{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #E7EBDA;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 2em 20em;
    height: 50px;
}

header h1{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

header ul{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0.5em auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
}

header ul li{
    display: inline;
}

header ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    border: solid;
    border-color: #7D8471;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #7D8471;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.3em;
}

header ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #B8B799;
    border-color: #B8B799;
}

header ul li a:active{
    padding: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1 class="al-iz">logo</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul class="al-der">
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Al header le di una altura

Comment: creo que deberías revisar el código, le di ejecutar a la muestra que dejaste y sale todo al centro

Comment: Si, me pasó lo mismo jajaja, pero como te dije, al lado del botón ejecutar, a la derecha sale un link que dice "pagina completa" si le das click vas a ver la página como corresponde

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer que header se tenga un `display:flex` y colocarle un `justify-content:space-between` o `space-around` es creo la manera mas facil de hacerlo.

```
header{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
background-color: #E7EBDA;
padding: 0.5em;
margin: 2em 20em;
```

}

reemplaza tu .header por esto, queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]